# Switch with unknown number of cases - a default case that slightly changes?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, switch-statement, google-sheets

I have a switch statement with an unknown amount of cases. After case 1, each case outputs the same formula. The only difference in the formula is the number inside the rationaleLabels array. It starts at rationaleLabels[0] in case 2; then in case 3, it is rationaleLabels[1]; case 4 - rationaleLabels[2]; and so on. Is there a way that I can set a default case that increments the number inside the rationaleLabel array if the case occurs?

```js
for(i = 0; i < drugs.length; i++){
            rationaleTable[i] = [];
          for(j = 0; j < rationaleLabel.length; j++){
            switch(j){
              case 0:
                rationaleTable[j] = drugs[i];
                break;
              case 1:
                rationaleTable[j] = drugs[i];
                break;
              case 2:
                rationaleTable[j] = "=COUNTIFS('All Events'!$D:$D,\"*" + rationaleLabels[0] + "*\" , 'All Events;!$E:$E,\"" + drugs[i] + "*\")";
                break;  
              case 3:
                rationaleTable[j] = "=COUNTIFS('All Events'!$D:$D,\"*" + rationaleLabels[1] + "*\" , 'All Events;!$E:$E,\"" + drugs[i] + "*\")";
                break;  
              case 4:
                rationaleTable[j] = "=COUNTIFS('All Events'!$D:$D,\"*" + rationaleLabels[2] + "*\" , 'All Events;!$E:$E,\"" + drugs[i] + "*\")";
                break;   
              case 5:
                rationaleTable[j] = "=COUNTIFS('All Events'!$D:$D,\"*" + rationaleLabels[3] + "*\" , 'All Events;!$E:$E,\"" + drugs[i] + "*\")";
                break;  
              case 6:
                rationaleTable[j] = "=COUNTIFS('All Events'!$D:$D,\"*" + rationaleLabels[4] + "*\" , 'All Events;!$E:$E,\"" + drugs[i] + "*\")";
                break;  
              case 7:
                rationaleTable[j] = "=COUNTIFS('All Events'!$D:$D,\"*" + rationaleLabels[5] + "*\" , 'All Events;!$E:$E,\"" + drugs[i] + "*\")";
                break;       
               
            }      
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work:

```
for(j = 0; j < rationaleLabel.length; j++){

  if(j==0 || j==1) {
    rationaleTable[j] = drugs[i];
  } else {
     rationaleTable[j] = "=COUNTIFS('All Events'!$D:$D,\"*" + rationaleLabels[j -2 ] + "*\" , 'All Events;!$E:$E,\"" + drugs[i] + "*\")";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris. You were correct. I had a typo in the code. `rationaleLabel.length` should have been `rationaleLabels.length` This is now working.

Answer (score 1):

Would do it the same way as Chris, but still here is a modified Version of the Switch Case Idea:

```js
for(i = 0; i < drugs.length; i++){
            rationaleTable[i] = [];
          for(j = 0; j < rationaleLabel.length; j++){
            switch(j){
              case 0:                    
              case 1:
                rationaleTable[j] = drugs[i];
                break;
              default:
                rationaleTable[j] = "=COUNTIFS('All Events'!$D:$D,\"*" + rationaleLabels[j-2] + "*\" , 'All Events;!$E:$E,\"" + drugs[i] + "*\")";
                break;                  
               
            }      
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may implement cases 2 to 7 in the default (I mean the fallback case)
I do not know which language you are using but syntax should be very closed to the following:

```
switch(j) {
 ...
 default:
    rationaleTable[j] = "=COUNTIFS('All Events'!$D:$D,\"*"" + rationaleLabel[j-2] + ...
}
```